# Uninstall and reinstall HP QC 11.0

Tags: installation, uninstallation, hp-quality-center

I want to uninstall and re-install HP QC 11.0 in my machine. But, I am not able to figure out a way. It doesn't appear in Add/Remove programs also. I use Win XP.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about the Quality center client side application, it is present in the Add/Remove programs as "Quality Center Client Side". Have a check. I am also using ALM 11.